# How to count columns of an output csv file using robot script

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to get the column count from an output csv file using Robot script.

I tried the following lines. Count of rows is working fine. But the 'Get Column Count' is throwing error :
No keyword with name 'Get Column Count' found.

```
${file-content}=  Get File  ${OUTPUT_CSV_FILE}
${numberOfLine=}=  Get Line Count  ${file-content}
Should Be Equal As Integers  ${numberOfLine=}  X

${numberOfColumn=}=  Get Column Count  ${file-content}
Should Be Equal As Integers  ${columnCount=}  Y
```

I haven't defined any keywords for 'Get Line Count'..but its working.
Then why not Get Column Count. Is it necessary to write a keyword in robot?

Thanks in advance
Aneesh

Comment: Where are you getting the `Get File` keyword from? Are you using a csv library? The standard `Get File` keyword from the `OperatingSystem` library knows nothing about csv, it just opens files as plain text and thus doesn't know anything about columns.

Comment: Thanks Bryan for the reply. We are fetching the csv file from the server location and we dont use a csv library

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't defined any keywords for 'Get Line Count'..but its working. Then why not Get Column Count. Is it necessary to write a keyword in robot?

The reason why "Get line count" is working is that you have likely imported robot's [String](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html) library which has a keyword named [Get Line Count](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Line%20Count). It's not counting rows in a csv file, it's counting lines of text by splitting the string on newlines.

Robot doesn't itself have a keyword for counting columns in a csv file. For that you'll need to use a library that specifically imports the data as csv and has a keyword for counting columns.